# Match object between different video frames

Tags: c++, opencv

Am trying to use OPENCV to detect the shift in consecutive video frames when the camera is unstable and moving real time as shown in the picture.[image: two frames and the camera is a bit shifted in the angle]. To compensate the effect of shaking or changing in the angle I want to match some objects in the image as example the clock and from the center of the same object in the consecutive frames I can detect the shift value and compensate its effect. I don't know the way to do this real time or how many ways are available and accurate to do this. 
Thank you in advance and I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly standard operation, as it's actively used in MPEG-4 compression. It's called "motion estimation" and you don't do it on objects (too hard, requires image segmentation). In OpenCV, it's covered under [Video Stabilization](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d50/group__videostab.html#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will read your suggestion and see what I can come up with. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try writing code yourself then one method is to first of all crop the frame to produce a sub image of your actual image slightly smaller than your actual image along each dimension. This will give you some room to move.

Next you want to be able to find and track shapes in OpenCV - an example of code is here - http://opencv-srf.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/object-detection-tracking-using-contours.html - Play around until you get a few geometric primitive shapes coming up on each frame.

Next you want to build some vectors between the centres of each shape - these are what will determine the movement of the camera - if in the next frame most of the vectors are displaced but parallel that is a good indicator that the camera has moved.

The last step is to calculate the displacement, which should is matter of measuring the distance between detected parallel vectors. If this is smaller than your sub-image cropping then you can crop the original image to negate the displacement.

The pseudo code for each iteration would be something like -

```
//Variables
image wholeFrame1, wholeFrame2, subImage, shapesFrame1, shapesFrame2
vectorArray vectorsFrame1, vectorsFrame2; parallelVectorList
vector cameraDisplacement = [0,0]

//Display image
subImage = cropImage(wholeFrame1, cameraDisplacement)
display(subImage);

//Find shapes to track
shapesFrame1 = findShapes(wholeFrame1)
shapesFrame2 = findShapes(wholeFrame2)

//Store a list of parallel vectors
parallelVectorList = detectParallelVectors(shapesFrame1, shapesFrame2)

//Find the mean displacement of each pair of parallel vectors
cameraDisplacement = meanDisplacement(parallelVectorList)

//Crop the next image accounting for camera displacement
subImage = cropImage(wholeFrame1, cameraDisplacement)
```

There are better ways of doing it but this would be easy enough for someone doing their first attempt at image stabilisation with experience of OpenCV.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I will try to start with your code and I will feed u back with the results. and Vote up as start :D